# Sorted data structure that can be efficiently iterated

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures

I'm looking for an efficient data structure in C# to solve the following problem:

1. Store objects of a class grouped by a numeric field (for simplicity, say objects of a class `Person`, grouped by the field `age`).
2. Make addition, removal and look-up in the data structure as time-efficient as possible (memory efficiency is secondary).
3. Traverse the groups in the right order (say, from younger to older).

My first attempt was to use a sorted dictionary, like

```
SortedDictionary<int, AgeGroup> AgeGroups;
```

where `AgeGroup` is a collection of `Person` objects. It worked out as I expected for items 1) and 2), but item 3) became a real problem. I tried the most obvious approach to traverse the age groups, namely

```
foreach (var ageGroup in AgeGroups)
{
// do something
}
```

But this didn't go well because of garbage collection: after successive traverse operations, too many unreferenced objects created in the foreach loop must be collected, which became a real time-consuming problem.

Is there some other ready-to-use data structure that solves this problem? For example, one where the keys are arranged in a linked list or something, I don't know.

Ideas are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, a database does what you describe really well. If it's a small table, you'll likely find the whole table ends up cached in memory. I'm very curious about a) _"too many unreferenced objects created in the foreach loop must be collected_" - can you show us your loop's code? And b) how what should be Gen0-collectible objects cost you a lot in performance

Comment: A linked list is going to have horrendous insertion, removal, lookup, and traversal speeds for a sorted collection.  Much worse that basically any other mainstream data structure.

Comment: Linked lists are great at insertion and removal, but the are beyond the suck for iteration or lookup

Comment: »after successive traverse operations, too many unreferenced objects created in the foreach loop must be collected« a foreach loop does not create unreferenced objects and it certainly doesn't matter if you iterate a dictionary, sorteddictionary or a regular list. How did you come to the conclusion of the many unreferenced objects? How did you measure that? How big is your list/dictionary?

Comment: There are [sorted collection types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/sorted-collection-types)?

Comment: `SortedDictionary` is fine.  Maybe you had a problem in your `// do something`.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, maybe you're right, but I still didn't have the time to go through `// do something` carefully. But nevertheless, `foreach` does produce some garbage, right? Is there a way to avoid (or minimize) this? That would also be great.